# Codeigniter active record statement not running when sql query doesn't return anything

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I seem to be having a problem with the below code. I cannot get the insert query to run when the query returns nothing. But when there is a row in the db, the else statement runs correctly. Does anybody know why this could be happening?

```
$query5 = $this->db->get_where('loggedstatus', array('userid_loggedstatus' => $userid));

if ($query5->num_rows() < 0) {
    $data1 = array('isLoggedIn_loggedstatus' => 'yes', 'userid_loggedstatus' => $userid);
    $this->db->insert('loggedstatus', $data1);
} else {
    $data = array('isLoggedIn_loggedstatus' => 'yes');
    $this->db->where('userid_loggedstatus', $userid);
    $this->db->update('loggedstatus', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried changing this `if ($query5->num_rows() < 0) {` to something like `if ($query5->num_rows() <= 0) {`, just a thought. It would make a difference because your telling it to only execute if its `less than zero` however it might be `equal to zero` and you would skip to the else statement.

And just for `CodeIgniter` `num_rows()` reference:

```
/**
 * Number of rows in the result set
 *
 * @return  int
 */
public function num_rows()
{
    if (is_int($this->num_rows))
    {
        return $this->num_rows;
    }
    elseif (count($this->result_array) > 0)
    {
        return $this->num_rows = count($this->result_array);
    }
    elseif (count($this->result_object) > 0)
    {
        return $this->num_rows = count($this->result_object);
    }

    return $this->num_rows = count($this->result_array());
}
```

Comment: Yeah I actually tried it but gave up when I couldn't remember if it was =< or <=. I can't ever seem to remember it lol, thanks man, it works now

Comment: i have to wait a couple of minutes

Answer (score 7):

Changing if condition shown below should fix the problem.

```
if ($query5->num_rows() == 0)
```